# How to check the App Id from the AppTile object in PnP PowerShell for SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp-powershell

In PnP Powershell, I want to get a list of all my custom deployed web parts from (SPFx) and also check which all sites have them deployed to (they are non tenant wide installs). I have this script so far

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://mysite/sites/mysite" -UseWebLogin
$f = Get-PnPApp
foreach($fg in $f) {
    write-host $fg $fg.Title $fg.Id
}


$web = Get-PnPWeb -Includes AppTiles

$appTiles = $web.AppTiles
Invoke-PnPQuery

foreach ($appTile in $appTiles)
{
    if ($appType -eq "Instance")
    {
        write-host $appTile.Title $appTile.AppId $appTile.ProductId
    }
}
```

The top part gets all the solutions in the site collection along with its ID.

The next part gets all the app instances installed on the site. The weird thing is I can read the AppID and ProductID, but there does not seem to be a way to see the ID of the app that it is an instance of. I want to be able to tell which of the apps it is an instance of.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks